# Unit testing Ember.Object and DS.Model metaForProperty is inconsistent

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm working on building up unit tests for our Ember applications. The current set of tests I'm targeting are our Models. I've got a set of tests that work really well for Models based on Ember Data, but seem to fail when based on Ember.Object. Here are two examples:

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    First: DS.attr("string"),
    Last:  DS.attr("string")
});

App.Person2 = Ember.Object.extend({
    First: null,
    Last:  null
});
```

And the test which passes for DS.Model:

```
it('has a valid attribute: First', function() {
    var property = App.Person.metaForProperty('First');
    expect( property.type ).to.eql('string');
    expect( property.isAttribute ).to.eql(true);
});
```

Then, when using the same structure for Ember.Object:

```
it('has a valid attribute: First', function() {
    var property = App.Person2.metaForProperty('First');
});
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Assertion Failed: metaForProperty() could not find a computed property with key 'First'.
    at new Error (native)
    at Error.Ember.Error (http://0.0.0.0:3385/app/js/components/ember/ember.js:844:19)
    at Object.Ember.assert (http://0.0.0.0:3385/app/js/components/ember/ember.js:73:11)
    at Function.Mixin.create.metaForProperty (http://0.0.0.0:3385/app/js/components/ember/ember.js:13247:11)
    at Context.<anonymous> (http://0.0.0.0:3385/tests/model-person-test.js:6:35)
    at invoke (http://0.0.0.0:3385/tests/bower_components/ember-mocha-adapter/adapter.js:60:8)
    at Context.suite.on.context.it.context.specify.method (http://0.0.0.0:3385/tests/bower_components/ember-mocha-adapter/adapter.js:102:13)
    at Test.require.register.Runnable.run (http://0.0.0.0:3385/tests/assets/mocha.js:4200:15)
    at Runner.require.register.Runner.runTest (http://0.0.0.0:3385/tests/assets/mocha.js:4591:10)
    at http://0.0.0.0:3385/tests/assets/mocha.js:4637:12
```

Can anyone offer insight as to what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an updated set of assertions that work for me. It looks like because it's only using Ember.Object, the extra goodies from DS.Model simply aren't there.

```
it('has a valid attribute: First', function() {
    var person = App.Person.create({
            id: 1,
            First: 'Andy'
        });
    expect( App.Person.proto().hasOwnProperty('First') ).to.eql(true);
    expect(typeof person.get('First')).to.eql('string');
    expect(person.get('First')).to.eql('Andy');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, `First`/`Last` aren't computed properties on `Person2`, they are just properties.

This would work

```
App.Person2 = Ember.Object.extend({
    First: null,
    Last:  null,
    Blah: function(){

    }.property('First')
});

var j = App.Person2.metaForProperty('Blah');
console.log(j);
```

When you do DS.attr() Ember Data is actually injecting a computed property right there, see:  [Ember Data attr Source](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/model/attributes.js#L267)